# /bin/sh: r;: command not found

Tags: r, seurat

I am following the same script with the one shown here and describing the script in RStudio.

https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/multimodal_vignette.html#load-in-the-data-1

## Load in the RNA UMI matrix

```
library(Seurat)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
```

```
ccbmc.rna <- as.sparse(read.csv(file="multimodal_data/GSE100866_CBMC_8K_13AB_10X-RNA_umi.csv.gz", header = TRUE, sep = ",", row.names = 1))
```

However , I got the error ;
/bin/sh: r;Loadinthedata: command not found

Could you please give me the support for it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your whole script? How do you run it? in R Studio or in the terminal?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I run them in RStudio.

The codes shown above are all the code I described/used.

After I installed the "SeuratObject", this issue has been resolved.
Thank you for your kind support!!

Sincerely,